# Switch seems to be allowing only one device

Tags: dhcp, switch, local-area-network

I have a simple 5 port switch which I recently connected to the ethernet jack in my office. There is a main cisco switch for the entire office lan. Anyway all my devices were connected, I could check in the main office router where I could see all the new DHCP leases.

All my devices behind the switch were assigned an ip and working fine. After a few days only one device was working, and I could not get any other device to connect. My laptop simply got self assigned IP every time I tried to turn on the thunderbolt ethernet adapter. Once I unplugged everything and plugged back just my laptop (which is connected through a docking station) it started working fine and quickly acquired a IP address from the pool.

I noticed when I connect another device, unplug my laptop and reconnect my laptop, it takes a while to get DHCP and then just gets the self assigned IP and has no default route. I changed to a different switch and got the same problem. It is like only one device is allowed. But how could I have had it working before with all my devices. What could be some things I could troubleshoot, I am honestly out of ideas. I made sure there are enough IPs in the lan pool. Could it be the main cisco switch? Am I causing a loop or something else?

FYI -

1) the pi I used because of the way networking was setup, I could not access most web apps which were whitelisted by IP. I made a sock5 proxy on the pi and could then connect to VPN , activate my sock5 proxy and now could access internal wikis, kibanas etc. After that I realized all I needed was to just pass all traffic through the VPN connection when I remoted into the office. And NO, i'm not trying to break security or bypass something..

2) I now have a desktop which I want to remote into from my home using my laptop and have the desktop connection wired and super stable.

Comment: Cisco switch could have eizher Problems with thee arp tabe or has some filter options, aa its unclear how you get your ips, what kind of Devices you use etc

Comment: "Could it be the main cisco switch?" - Yes. Please post the configs from the main switch.

Comment: That sounds like a question you should be asking your IT support, not SE.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was my docking station hub. Once I connected my laptop directly to the switch, all my devices started working normally. This is the docking station I used in case anyones interested: CalDigit TS3 Plus Thunderbolt 3 Dock

Answer (score 0):

Is your Cisco switch configured for port-security where it allows the MAC address of the first address to connect and it locks that one in as the only one to be allowed. If you have access to this info this could explain the problem. In using the dock, it might change the MAC address and this MAC is blocked whereas your PC MAC is permitted.